# Knockout SelectedOptions binding to "Selected" property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/CsrrD/

Given an object

```
var viewModel = {
    Opts: ko.observableArray([
    { d: 'a', v: 0, selected: 1},
    { d: 'b', v: 1, selected: 1},
    { d: 'c', v: 2, selected: 1},
    { d: 'd', v: 3, selected: 2},
    { d: 'e', v: 4, selected: 1},
    { d: 'f', v: 5, selected: 1}
    ]), 
    selectedOpts: ko.observableArray([])
};
```

I want to bind a multiple select list to change the values of the 'selected' property, 1 being false, 2 being true. (how it is represented on the server - it is actually status codes)

```
<select data-bind="options: Opts,
    optionsText: 'd',
    optionsValue: 'v',
    selectedOptions: selectedOpts,
    optionsCaption: 'Choose...'" multiple=""></select>
```

​
I know that I wouldn't need the selectedOpts object if I could bind the selectedOptions binding to the selected property, I am just not getting how to do this simply without setting up a manual subscription to selectedOpts to see the list of values and manually setting the selected property on each item that has been selected.

I am sure there is an easy way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual subscriptions aren't so scary and can be very useful. I've modified your fiddle to demonstrate how easy this would be to accomplish if you just make the selected property observable:

http://jsfiddle.net/CsrrD/4/

Just a tip from a design perspective, the subscription function should probably live in your viewModel object and you may want to use the mapping plugin to avoid manual observable creation, but you get the idea.

Comment: Yep this is the approach that I originally considered, and am going to take. The real viewmodel that we have in the solution is a 'mapped' viewmodel, I was just being simple for the example. Thanks daedalus28 :)

Comment: I edited the fiddle to my specific use - http://jsfiddle.net/CsrrD/
Thanks again. In my solution I also added a manual loop before ko.applyBindings to look in the opts to see if any were status 2/1 and update the selectedOpts array accordingly in case of an edit view.

Comment: These fiddles seem to be gone. Any chance of re-uploading?

Comment: Downvoted as fiddle is gone, this answer is now useless

Answer (score 2):

There is not really a way to automatically do what you want.

Some options that you would have:

- setup a manual subscription to the observableArray, as you indicated, and loop through the options to set the value based on whether it is in the array
- create your options so that `selected` is a computed observable that keeps itself updated based on whether it is in the array.  The downside is that each option would have a computed that fires whenever the observableArray is updated (less efficient than a single manual subscription)
- write a custom binding that looks for the `selectedOptions` and does the subscription in the binding.  Maybe you would provide a function to execute on each option like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ds2aE/

Comment: Thanks RP. I like your example for the custom binding but I think it may be overengineering as the manual subscription/loop seems very simple, as illustrated by daedalus28 below.

Comment: Yes, I would use a manual subscription.  Just wanted to let you know about a few options that you have.